# Copy To in attribute mapping and generic Mapping with reflection in 2.x

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest, system.reflection, elasticsearch-net

For the attribute part, is there any form to tell NEST to use **copy to** by attributes? I want to create my mapping dynamically, so that I don't code the field property when creating my `CreateIndexDescriptor` object.

Example of attribute mapping:

```
[String(Analyzer="analyzer_shingles")]
public string company_no { get; set; }
```

Now for the reflection part...
Is there any way to use the `Map<T>` method dynamically?

Example of non-dynamic Mapping:

```
var mapperTemplate = new CreateIndexDescriptor(string.Format("customers"))
  .Settings(s => s
    .Analysis(a => a
      .Analyzers(an => an
        .UserDefined("analyzer_shingles", shingles)
        .UserDefined("didYouMean", didYouMean)
      )
    )
  );
var customer = mapperTemplate.Mappings(ms => ms
  .Map<customer>(m => m
    .AllField(a => a.Analyzer("analyzer_shingles"))
    .AutoMap()
  )
);
```

I've tried obtaining the methods and passing new lambdas, but I'm stuck at passing parameters to the `Map` method.
I can't find a form to use `MakeGenericType` on:

```
new Func<TypeMappingDescriptor<T>, ITypeMapping>
```

Also, `Map` with a  `TypeName` parameter doesn't seem to do the work.

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about why you want to map _dynamically_? Perhaps there is another way to do what you are trying to achieve

Comment: I have a POCO classes generator that takes a list of sql server tables. Maybe sometimes I want to index different tables, and I don't want to edit my code just for that. I **solved** the whole Issue of NEST by creating a json dynamically for every table.